# jquery remove table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm having a problem removing a table row, I can highlight the row red but when I try to remove it the slideup function messes up. I have wrapped them in a div but I don't no how to access the children of the tr and then the children of that?

```
$('#test tr:not(:first)').click(function()
        {           
            $(this).css("background-color","red");  

            $(this).children("td div").slideUp(function()
            {    
                $(this).parent().remove(); 
            });              
        });
```

The problem is this line:

```
$(this).children("td div").slideUp(function()
```

I also tried

```
$(this).children("td").children("div").slideUp(function()
```

The slide up only removes the first column.

```
<table border="1" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="test">
    <tr>
        <td><b>First Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Last Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Address</b></td>
        <td><b>Town</b></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><div>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Town</div></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Do I need to wrap the content of each `<td>` with a `div` tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `children("td div")` will find all *direct children* that match the selector. (all children which are `<div>`s that happen to be inside of `<td>`s)
Since all of the direct children are `<td>`s, it won't match anything.

Calling `children("td").children("div")` will find all `<div>`s inside of all `<td>`s.
It will thus find the only `<div>` you have there.

**EDIT**: You can use jQuery to create wrapper elements; [see my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/animating-table-rows-with-jquery.html):

```
$('#test tr:not(:first)').click(function() {           
    $(this).css("background-color","red");  

    $(this).children().wrapInner('<div>').children().slideUp(function() {    
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

[*Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/JvfPu/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now I got abit confused about the children. Is there a easier way without having to use a div for each TD? It works with a div for each...but its abit "hacky".

Comment: @Elliot: Yes.  However, jQuery can do that for you!

Comment: @Elliott: You should actually call `wrapInner` instead of `contents().wrap`; otherwise, it won't behave well if there are multiple children in the `<td>` elements (I edited to show this).  Sorry.